# V4L2: What happens when the queue is full

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, v4l2

In video capture mode, what happens when the queue is full and a new frame comes in?

Does the kernel drop frames? If so, does the newest frame (just arrived) get dropped or the oldest one in the queue gets dropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if the queue becomes full kernel drops the buffer newest frame which just arrived, if no more buffers are available. So to avoid this you need to allocate more buffers (REQBUF) and queue back (QBUF) the buffer quickly when done in userspace.

Comment: Thanks. But can I configure the kernel in some way such that it drops the oldest frame in the queue and enqueues the newest frame which just arrived?

Comment: The reason why the driver is dropping the buffer because it has none available all of them are with  userspace, so the driver just cannot revoke the buffer from user space and write new frame into it.

Comment: Ok this makes much sense. Thanks!